# Shopify App - Script Tag - CORS error when retrieving data from store

Tags: reactjs, rest, koa, shopify-app, script-tag

**Overview**

I have a custom REST API within my Koa server and I can access it just fine within my Shopify app using react. However, when I try to access it from my Script Tag, I get a CORS error.

**Issue**

I can't access my custom REST API data from the script tag, but I can access it from Postman & my React app.

**What I tried**

1. Install [koa/cors](https://github.com/koajs/cors) and set {origin: *}

**Code**

server.js

```
   server
      .use(router.routes())
      .use(router.allowedMethods())
      .use(CORS({ origin: "*" }));

      router.get("/api/test", async (ctx, next) => {
        ctx.body = {
          llama: "123",
        };
      });
```

script_tag.js

```
  async function hello() {
    await _loadScript(
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js",
    );
    const data = await window.axios.get(
      "https://3b1b4258759f.ngrok.io/api/test?shop=panda-app-tests.myshopify.com",
      {
        crossDomain: true,
      },
    );
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Any ideas how I can go around this without using [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)? Thank you very much in advance.

**Images**
[image: API request]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It ended up being a silly mistake. I had to add the `koa-cors` middleware before all the others. Therefore, in the `server.js` file it should be like this:

```
server
  .use(CORS({ origin: "*" }))
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved my issues having blocked requests due to Option-Preflight requests.

Comment: You're welcome, my friend! Wishing you a nice week ahead.